# @PropertyName not working in Kotlin with Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, serialization, google-cloud-firestore

I have troubles with Firestore as @PropertyName is totally ignored with data classes.

```
import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName




data class Profile(
    @get:PropertyName("player_uuid")
    @set:PropertyName("player_uuid")
    @PropertyName("player_uuid")
    var playerUuid: String? = null,
   }
```

I've tried all combinations of annotations but none of them seem to work, because player Uuid will always be null when I get it from the server.

How I parse the object -

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("profile/$id").get().await().toObject(Profile::class.java)
```

Same thing happens when I set the document

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("profile/$id").set(profile).await()
```

On the firebase console, I will send playerUuid instead of player_uuid.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the import that adds @PropertyName

Comment: @DougStevenson done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong import for Firestore.  The one you have now is for Realtime Database.  Use [`import com.google.firebase.firestore.PropertyName`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) instead.

Comment: And is enough just  PropertyName, or I have to provide both get: and set: annotations?

Comment: I don't remember ever having to use get and set, but then again, I might have only been working with Java at the time I used PropertyName.  It was a couple years ago.  In Java, I think you only have to annotate the getter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add @Keep to your class. Or Proguard will rename the variables
Check in firestore datatabase if the field names are the variable names

```
@Keep
data class Profile(
@get:PropertyName("player_uuid")
@set:PropertyName("player_uuid")
var playerUuid: String? = null)
```

Comment: I am not using proguard.